# Type Redefinition With WSE Web Service Import

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, wse, wse3.0

Consider the following Visual Studio project structure

- ProjectA.csproj

  - AClass.cs
- ProjectB.csproj

  - References

    - ProjectA
  - Web References

    - AWebService
- AWebService.csproj

  - References

    - ProjectA
  - ReturnAClassViaWebService.asmx

The issue occurs when ProjectB adds the web reference to AWebService and automatically generates all the proxy code for accessing AWebService including a new implementation of AClass.  Since all of our other code needs to use the AClass defined in ProjectA, we're forced to convert the AWebService.AClass returned from the service into something we can use.

We're currently considering two solutions, neither of which are ideal.

- Manually editing the generated Reference.cs to remove new definitions of AClass
- Serializing AWebService.AClass to a stream then deserializing to ProjectA.AClass

Does anyone have any better solutions?  This seems like something common enough for other developers to have experienced it.

Ideally we would like to have the proxy code generated in ProjectB to reference ProjectA.AClass rather than generating a whole new implementation.

Our environment is VS 2008 using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Were you aware that WSE is obsolete?

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative that works within .NET 2.0?

Comment: No, I can't. Why not upgrade to .NET 4.0? It's almost a no-brainer.

Comment: Because its not my decision :(.  We have to deploy to constrained environments.

Comment: @matheeny: the question wasn't meant for you, so much as it was meant for those who make the decisions. This kind of problem will continue to happen as long as you use obsolete software.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'll point the decision makers to this thread the next time they're asking for justification to move to later .NET versions.

Comment: @matheeny: point them to the following search: http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?query=%22Web+Services+Enhancements%22+3.0&catalog=LCID%3D1033&mode=r. They should be very afraid that a search of the Microsoft Support site finds only 11 hits for WSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem that you are describing and I have tried both of the options you specify without being entirely happy about either of them.

The reason we both have this issue is at least partly because the *shared-library-between-consumer-and-provider-of-a-web-service*-solution is in violation of accepted patterns and practices for [web service design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954638.aspx). On the consumer side, it *should* be sufficient to know the interface published in the WSDL.

Still, if you are prepared to accept a tight coupling between your web service provider and web service consumer and you *know* for certain that your current client will never be replaced by a different client (which might not be capable of referencing the shared library), then I understand why the proposed solution seems like a neat way to structure your app. IMPORTANT NOTE: Can we really honestly answer yes to both of these questions? Probably not.

To recap:

1. The issue appears when you have classes (e.g. a strongly typed dataset) defined in some sort of shared library (used on both client and server).
2. Some of your shared classes are used in the interface defined by your web service.
3. When the web reference is added there are proxy classes defined (for your shared classes) within the web reference namespace.
4. Due to the different namespaces the proxy class and its actual counterpart in the shared library are incompatible.

Here are four solutions that can be tried if you want to go ahead with the shared library setup:

1. Don't. Use the proxy class on the client side. This is how it is intendend to be done. It works fine unless you simultaneously want to leverage aspects of the shared library that are not exposed by the web service WSDL.
2. Implement or use a provided copy/duplication feature of the class (e.g. you could try to Merge() one strongly typed dataset into another). A Cast is obviosuly not possible, and the copy option is usually not a very good solution either since it tends to have undesirable side-effects. E.g. When you Merge a dataset into another, all the rows in the target dataset will be labeled as 'changed'. This could be resurrected with AcceptChanges(), but what if a couple of the received rows *were* actually changed.
3. Serialize everything - except for elementary data types - into strings (and back again on the consumer side). Loss of type safety is one important weakness of this approach.
4. Remove the explicit declaration of the shared class in Reference.cs and strip the namespace from the shared class wherever it is mentioned within Reference.cs. This is probably the best option. You get what *you* really wanted. The shared class is returned by the web service. The only irritating drawback with this solution is that your modifications to the reference.cs file is lost whenever you update your web reference. Trust me: It can be seriously annoying.

Here is a link to a [similar discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/428573-web-service-references-namespace-problem):

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse existing referenced types between the client and service by clicking on the 'Advanced' button on the 'Add Service Reference' form.  Make sure the 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' checkbox is checked and when the service client is generated it should reuse all types from project A.

In past versions this has not always worked correctly and I've had to explicitly select the shared type assemblies by selecting the 'Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies' option and then checking the appropriate assemblies in the list box.  However, I just tested this with VS 2008 SP1 and it appears to work as expected.  Obviously, you need to make sure that the types that are being used by the service and client projects are both from project A.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: +1: Would rather the bounty go to this answer than the one from Airslash even though it doesn't actually solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

We encountered a similar problem with one of our projects. Because we had several dependencies, we ended up creating a circular reference because project 1 required objects from project 2, but project 2 could not be build before project 3, which relied on project 1 to be build.

To solve this problem, we extracted all the public standalone classes from both projects and placed them inside a single librarie. In the end we created something like this:

- Framework.Objects
- Framework.Interface
- Framework.Implementation
- WebService

The WebService would be linked to all projects in our case, whereas external parties would only be linking to the objects and interface classes to work with. The actuall implementation was coupled at runtime through reflection.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the issue we're having isn't being caused by circular dependencies.  Rather, its the generated classes in the WebService Proxy classes that override the "real" classes.

Comment: that's odd...
I'm keeping an eye on this topic as it's interesting for myself, and i'd like to know how you solved it. I've never had such an issue where the generated classes from the references overwrite your own :S